# How to check an awesomenaut characteristics?

Tags: awesomenauts

Is it possible to check an awesomenaut characteristics (like max health, attack speed, etc.) during the game?
There are number of effects, which increase health after a kill for example, so I think there should be a way to check how much health you get already. But I can not find it.

And second question would be, is there in The internet info about awesomenauts, that is up to date? [gamepedia](http://awesomenauts.gamepedia.com/Awesomenauts_Wiki) gives numbers quite different from those I see in the game. The [official site](http://www.awesomenauts.com) doesn't show any numerical characteristics at all, or may be I missed the page.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can check max and current health value on the horizontal bar in the bottom of your screen. I still do not know how to check exact numbers, but you can see attack damage as numbers, that flights out from your target (for some nauts they should be multiplied by 2). No idea how to check attack speed.
2. I found this site: http://nautsbuilder.com . It provides up to date info (official site gives a link to it, so it should be trustworthy), and it allows you to see accumulative characteristics after you bough something, for example: [Ayla's build](http://nautsbuilder.com/#Ayla/1030200122010012102001301010/19-19-23-23-23-8-9-9-10-10-12-25-1-3-3-3-5-5-27-17-16-16).